# business entity cross country relocation

Tags: corporate-law

Is it possible to relocate a company from a country A to a country B? Lets say that in both these two countries are there is an approximate equivalent of the company type, say private company limited by shares, in UK an Ltd.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### No

Each country (and sometimes each state/province) has their own laws and registration requirements for companies.

It is possible to transfer a *business* and other assets from one company to another (within or across jurisdictions) - this will usually have tax implications. It is also usually possible to operate in a country with a foreign company.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I ask what do you mean by "transferring a business"?

Comment: @Mr.Davidson of course you may ask, that’s what this site is for.